# Compare document with database

Tags: php, file, matching

on my server i have a folder, named: old_files
In that folder there are a couple of 100 documents.

I also have a database with an column named "filename" and a column named "transferFlag".

Now i want to read out the files in the Folder, compare the names of the files with the values in column "FILENAME" and is they match, update the column "transferFlag" to "NO" where the filename matches.

But i don't have a clue how to arrange this? Can somebody give me advise?

This is what i was thinking of:

```
$filename = 'http://www.mysite.com/old_files/';
$inhoud =  file_get_contents($filename);
```

But how to get all the files in the folder and compare them one by one with the values in the DB?

---

Well, i now did this:

```
$dir = dirname(__FILE__)."/../files/oud/"; // de directory die hij uit moet lezen
if ($handle = @opendir($dir))
{
while (false !== ($file = @readdir($handle))) {
    $bestand = $dir ."/". $file ;
    $ext = pathinfo($bestand);

                $sql_2 = "UPDATE documenten SET transfer_vlag = ''     WHERE documentnaam = '".$file."'";

                mysql_query($sql_2) or die(mysql_error());      

            }


@closedir($handle);
}
```

Only problem:

there are like 1000 files in the directory, so i get an time-out after a while.
What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Use [glob](http://php.net/glob) for getting all the files from a directory..

```
foreach (glob("*.txt") as $filename) {
   $inhoud =  file_get_contents($filename);
}
```